# How can I access to the localized strings inside Settings.bundle in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I need to access to the Settings.bundle and get the descriptions and titles with the localized string.

[image: Settings.bundle]

Comment: Have you looked into using `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`?

Comment: Actually, I used NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue, but that also works

Answer (score 1):

Use [NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocalizedstringfromtableinbundle) function. Create an instance of `NSBundle` with URL of your bundle and use it as `bundle` argument. Use “Root” as the table name for `tbl` argument.

For example:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithURL: ...];
NSString *string = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle("SOME_KEY", "Root", bundle, "Comment");
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end I did it this way:

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *settingsBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:resourcePath];
NSURL *url = [settingsBundle URLForResource:@"Root" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSArray *preferences = dictionary[@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];

for (NSDictionary *dic in preferences){
    NSString *localizedTitle = NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(dic[@"Title"], @"Root", settingsBundle, dic[@"Title"], @"");
}
```